# Generate insert statements with foreign key constraints

Tags: sql-server, database, insert

I have an issue where an entire tables worth of data was deleted. It is a child table, and contains its own Primary Key, a Foreign Key to its parent and some other data.

I tried using Merge, generated from a stored procedure I found here:
https://github.com/readyroll/generate-sql-merge

This generates a giant merge statement for your whole table. That worked ok for a while, but I've since found that records from a parent table have since been deleted, and Merge doesn't handle this too well.

I've tried rewriting it, but I'm getting bogged down in it and it feels like something somebody else will have done before.

What I'd really like is a way to generate 1000's of insert statements with an If Exists above each one saying

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select PK from ChildTable where ID = <about to be inserted>) AND EXISTS (select FK from ParentTable where ID = <about to be inserted>)
   INSERT RECORD
   OUTPUT PK TO LOG TABLE
```

Theres about 20,000 records so its really something I don't want to have to do by hand, and because the delete event happened several times over a few months, I need to generate the data from several different databases to recreate the whole picture.

I'd like to keep the inserted Ids in a log table, so I can tell whats been inserted, and so the data could be restored to a prescript state for any reason.

Any advice on my approach would also be welcome.

Thanks :)

Comment: What part of this don't you know how to do?   Generating INSERT statements is just simple string building.   Is there some reason it's more complicated than that?

Comment: The reason it was so complicated was because of the sheer volume of inserts I was generating. 20000 inserts with corresponding IFs etc was crushing my computer, and SQL would not process it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long story short is I tried a few ways to fix this, and the best was to generate Insert statements for the table using SQL Generate scripts, and bring them into a temp table.

Because I only wanted to import 90% of the data, and exclude specific records based on a few conditions, I originally thought I should wrap each Insert with an IF, but 20,000 IFs broke down when trying to create a query plan.

Instead, I inserted all the records without a filter into a temp table. I then deleted all the records I didn't want from this table with a couple of Delete statements.

Lastly I then said for all remaining data in the temp table, insert it into the actual proper table, where the data was originally missing from.

This worked perfectly, and SQL Manager was able to run without crashing. It was also a lot clearer what I was doing, and I didn't have to add lots of complicated IFs in a string builder.

I also used OUTPUT on the insert into to log all the record Ids I'd inserted, to give the audit trail like I needed.

As for the string builder, the query was so long and complicated, and Excel was moaning about a 256 char limit, I ended up using 20+ columns to build up my query after concat'ing 26 columns of data. When I used the auto formula drag feature in Excel, it would crash my machine going across so many records, and I have a pretty grunty machine!

Using the Script Generate, rather than the string builder also had the benefit of not altering the data in anyway. It was purley like for like, so weird characters and new lines etc were no issue.